# Strange Behavior with DeletedDatabaseRecord

Tags: acumatica

I would like to use logical deletion in a custom screen and I have added the following to my DAC:

```
        #region DeletedDatabaseRecord
        public abstract class deletedDatabaseRecord : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected bool? _DeletedDatabaseRecord;
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? DeletedDatabaseRecord
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DeletedDatabaseRecord;
            }
            set
            {
                this._DeletedDatabaseRecord = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

The above DAC is used in a grid (in a master/detail screen). When I click on the grid delete and then save, the row gets marked as deleted in the database.
However, when I refresh the screen, the deleted rows appear again. It seems that the data view is not taking into DeletedDatabaseRecord value. I confirmed that this was set to 1 in the database.

My data view is as follows:

```
public PXSelect<DCRule, Where<DCRule.ruleHeaderID, Equal<Current<DCRuleHeader.ruleHeaderID>>>, OrderBy<Asc<DCRule.sequence>>> Rules;
```

Shouldn't the data view, automatically filter out deleted records (where DeletedDatabaseRecord  = 1)? or should I handle something else in the code logic.

UPDATE 1

I have removed the DeletedDatabaseRecord  from the DAC as the Design Guidelines state that they should not be included. However, I am still having the exact same issue.

UPDATE 2

I also noticed that the SQL statement is not filtering out the deleted records, and it is also not returning it as a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CompanyID column to the table where you use DeletedDatabaseRecord. After that deleted row should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

One should never declare DAC fields for the following columns:

- CompanyID
- CompanyMask
- DeletedDatabaseRecord

When you make some to Acumatica database schema, it's always a good practice to restart IIS or recycle the app pool hosting your Acumatica website, so Acumatica can re-sync the updated DB schema during domain restart as it does not track database schema changes at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have removed the DAC field. Restarted the machine, publish with cleanup. But still the same issue. Acumatica is not filtering out the DeletedDatabaseRecord

Comment: Should be working now... Do you mind starting with a brand new website? In case something got cached or corrupted with your current one.

Comment: No, I didn't try it. But will do it and let you know.

Comment: Tried with a blank site, but no luck. Still the same issue.